# Unsupported class file major version 61 Cordova Mac

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

So im on mac (Big sur), and i wish to build a Cordova app to android. I have **java 17** installed, and **gradle 7.1.1**.

Im able to build the project on another windows computer just fine. (though i cannot rely on that for personal reasons)

But every time i try to build on mac, im  confronted with following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/me/app/cordovaProject/platforms/android/settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '/Users/me/app/cordovaProject/platforms/android/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

(There is more to the error but its long. Will provide if needed.)

Comment: I think class version 61 should be compatible with Java 17.  Are you sure 17 is the version that is being used when this error occurs?

Comment: `java -version` Returns `java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS` in the terminal so I do think so.

Comment: Seems like a bug.

Comment: So nothing i can do?

Comment: "So nothing i can do?" - No idea.  I am sorry I can't help.

Comment: Is your gradle new enough for java 17?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I mentioned that i use gradle 7

Comment: Try updating to Gradle 7.3.3. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16857

Comment: Have tried doing so, didn't work.

Comment: For a workaround, use JDK 16. The error says that 'Class version 61 is unsupported'. '61' here refers to JDK 17. So either upgrade your Gradle version, or use JDK 16. Also, post the log after running 'gradlew -v' command, after upgrading gradle. To upgrade gradle, modify the gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: @JustInCoding Would i have to remove Jdk 17 to use Jdk 16?

Comment: Umm, no. You can keep both JDKs side-by-side. Install the zipped JDK 16, unzip it somewhere, and then point the org.gradle.java.home variable in gradle.properties towards it.

Comment: @JustInCoding Might as well let you know your method worked like a charm. Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. You can post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. I won't mind :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answered by @JustInCoding, the solution for me was to **install JDK 16**, and then add `org.gradle.java.home=your Jdk 16 path here` in  the `gradle.properties` file of my project.

Comment: April 2022: this issue is still resolve using JDK 16. I'm using windows so my path is `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.2`

Comment: on the official page, it says JDK 16 has been suspended, https://jdk.java.net/16 i guess the second answer should be the most recent accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution that worked for me was to update gradle to 7.4.2.

Comment: Still the same error for me